# Get Country using ip address and output New Year Countdown according to that

Tags: javascript, php

Here I am trying to retrieve the IP address of the user, and with the timezone that I got from the IP address, I want to check if the date is 1/01/2023 for that country and then if it is, I want to  redirect the user to another subdomain which has a Happy New Year Page:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipInfo = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $ip);
$ipInfo = json_decode($ipInfo);
$timezone = $ipInfo->timezone;
if (date('d') == '01' && date('m') == '01' && date('Y') == '2023') {
  header('Location: https://2023.blogsaffair.com/');
}

if (date('d') == '1' && date('m') == '11') {
  header('Location: https://blogsaffair.com');
}*/
?>
```

My scripts.js code for countdown

```
const secondsText = document.getElementById('seconds');
const minutesText = document.getElementById('minutes');
const hoursText = document.getElementById('hours');
const daysText = document.getElementById('days');

function countDown () {
    var deadlineDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2023 00:00:00").getTime();
    var presentDate= new Date().getTime();
    var timeLeft = deadlineDate - presentDate;
    var daysValue = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hoursValue = Math.floor(timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutesValue = Math.floor(timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
    var secondsValue = Math.floor(timeLeft % (1000 * 60) / (1000));

    secondsText.textContent = secondsValue;
    minutesText.textContent = minutesValue;
    hoursText.textContent = hoursValue;
    daysText.textContent = daysValue;

    if(timeLeft < 0){
        clearInterval();
    }   
}

setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```

I am trying to achieve what timeanddate.com shows on this link https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/newyear

How can I display the countdown for that country using IP. I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet so please help if you can? Thanks!

Comment: What specific issue are you having in the code you've shown?

Comment: cannot achieve displaying the countdown using IP address. I hope you can help!

Comment: Note : [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) requires a parameter : `intervalID`.